# Is there a way to combine mosaic plots using different data sets so that they are outputted next to each other?

Tags: r, r-markdown, mosaic

I am trying to combine 20 mosaic plots onto one output. par(mfrow=...) is not working. I would like the rows to have 3 plots in each row.

Here is code for just 4 of the plots that I am using:

```
library(vcd)
library(vcdExtra)
library(MASS)

All <- matrix(c(599,250,39,24, 157,238,89,40, 26,51,51,45, 26,26,30,57), 4, 4)
dimnames(All) <- list("2002" =c("Never","Light","Moderate","Heavy"), "2014" =c("Never","Light","Moderate","Heavy"))
All <- as.table(All)

Poor <- matrix(c(184,57,7,6, 51,43,12,6, 9,10,6,6, 9,5,9,11), 4, 4)
dimnames(Poor) <- list("2002"=c("Never","Light","Moderate","Heavy"), "2014" =c("Never","Light","Moderate","Heavy"))
Poor <- as.table(Poor)

NonPoor <- matrix(c(376,180,30,18, 94,192,77,34, 12,40,43,39, 15,19,21,41), 4, 4)
dimnames(NonPoor) <- list("2002"=c("Never","Light","Moderate","Heavy"), "2014" =c("Never","Light","Moderate","Heavy"))
NonPoor <- as.table(NonPoor)

Black <- matrix(c(239,82,7,6, 54,56,15,9, 8,12,9,5, 12,11,8,8), 4, 4)
dimnames(Black) <- list("2002"=c("Never","Light","Moderate","Heavy"), "2014" =c("Never","Light","Moderate","Heavy"))
Black <- as.table(Black)

mosaic(All, shade = TRUE, rot_labels = c(top = 90, left=0),just_labels = c("left","right","right","right"),offset_labels = c(-.4, 0, 0, 0),offset_varnames = c(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5))

mosaic(Poor, shade = TRUE, rot_labels = c(top = 90, left=0),just_labels = c("left","right","right","right"),offset_labels = c(-.4, 0, 0, 0),offset_varnames = c(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5))

mosaic(NonPoor, shade = TRUE, rot_labels = c(top = 90, left=0),just_labels = c("left","right","right","right"),offset_labels = c(-.4, 0, 0, 0),offset_varnames = c(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5))

mosaic(Black, shade = TRUE, rot_labels = c(top = 90, left=0),just_labels = c("left","right","right","right"),offset_labels = c(-.4, 0, 0, 0),offset_varnames = c(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5))
```

I did something similar earlier with bar plots and it worked just using the par(mfrow=...). Thank you in advance!

Comment: `par(mfrow=...)` is for base graphics, but `vcd::mosaic` is built on grid graphics, so you can't use that. unfortunately, `mosaic` doesn't return a grid object, so you can't use something like `gridExtra::grid.arrange` directly. There is an example you can use in `?Ord_plot`, but it is a bit verbose. Or maybe `?mplot` is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit tricky with VCD graphics
try this approach

```
library(gridExtra)

fig1<-grid.grabExpr(mosaic(All, shade = TRUE, rot_labels = c(top = 90, left=0),just_labels = c("left","right","right","right"),offset_labels = c(-.4, 0, 0, 0),offset_varnames = c(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5)))
fig2<-grid.grabExpr(mosaic(Poor, shade = TRUE, rot_labels = c(top = 90, left=0),just_labels = c("left","right","right","right"),offset_labels = c(-.4, 0, 0, 0),offset_varnames = c(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5)))
fig3<-grid.grabExpr(mosaic(NonPoor, shade = TRUE, rot_labels = c(top = 90, left=0),just_labels = c("left","right","right","right"),offset_labels = c(-.4, 0, 0, 0),offset_varnames = c(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5)))
fig4<-grid.grabExpr(mosaic(Black, shade = TRUE, rot_labels = c(top = 90, left=0),just_labels = c("left","right","right","right"),offset_labels = c(-.4, 0, 0, 0),offset_varnames = c(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5)))



grid.arrange(fig1,fig2,fig3,fig4)
```